# Sidekiq Log redirection fails when process is launched inside docker container

Tags: docker, logging, containers, sidekiq

I am running sidekiq and redirecting all logs to a specific file (this works fine):

```
bundle exec sidekiq -r ./artifacts_scraper.rb 2>&1 | tee ./log/sidekiq.log
```

However when I start a docker container with this very same command, sidekiq is launched but the log redirection doesnt work anymore (the ultimate goal being to store the logs on the host machine through the use of a docker "volume").

Here's the docker-compose file (relevant part being the sidekiq service) :

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: redis
  scraper:
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts-scraper:without-db
    command: 'ruby ./scrape_sources.rb'
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis-server:6379/0
      - ARTIFACTS_ENV=docker_development
      - DATA_API_BASE=http://data_api:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/artifacts_scraper
    depends_on:
      - data_api
      - redis-server
  data_api:
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts_data_api:latest
    command: 'rails server -b 0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./log/production.log:/artifacts_data_api/log/docker_development.log
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=docker_development
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=docker_development_secret
  sidekiq:
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts-scraper:without-db
    command: 'bundle exec sidekiq -r ./artifacts_scraper.rb 2>&1 | tee ./log/sidekiq.log'
    volumes:
      - ./log/sidekiq.log:/usr/src/artifacts_scraper/log/sidekiq.log
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis-server:6379/0
      - ARTIFACTS_ENV=docker_development
      - DATA_API_BASE=http://data_api:3000
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
      - data_api
```

and a link to the project that sidekiq uses to run :
[https://github.com/davidgeismar/artifacts-scraper/tree/removing-db](https://github.com/davidgeismar/artifacts-scrapper/tree/removing-db)

Why does the log redirection works fine on my local development machine and fails inside the docker container ?